# Using Powershell to move documents to a folder based on file name

Tags: powershell

I have searched your database for answers and find things that are similar, but not quite what I am needing. I do not know how to code well enough to take some of the examples and modify them to fit my needs.

I have documents that I need to move to a folder that has the same name as the beginning of the document name. Here are a couple of example of my document names (ParcelNum_CountyNum_Year_DocType.pdf)

- 188777_014_2013_NOAV.pdf
- 242353_227_2014_HRGNOTICE.pdf
- R506275_246_2013_NOAV.pdf

I currently have the documents residing in a single folder named by the county number (the 3 digit number between the first _ and the 2nd _)

I have folders created that are named by the ParcelNum, which is the first set of characters/numbers at the beginning and before the first _. I need Powershell to read the first portion of the document name stopping at the first _ and place it in the folder that matches that numchar.
So for example the first document example above is named 188777_014_2013_NOAV.pdf and resides at the root of the CountyNum folder named 014.
For that example, I would need it to be moved from the root folder 014, into its subfolder named 188777.

I hope that makes sense. Please feel free to ask questions.

Thank you,

Comment: We would like to see what you have coded so far.

Comment: I do not know how to code well enough to do this, and I am just now trying to learn Powershell. I am not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do. This is under the assumption that the files you want to move are in a parent folder and the root & sub folders you want to sort them to are also in the same folder, i.e. if the example PDF's path is `C:\test\Docs\188777_014_2013_NOAV.pdf` and you want it to end up in `C:\test\Docs\014\188777`.

Update the path in the $basePath variable to your liking. Comments are included above each step with explanations. Enjoy!

```
# This is the parent directory for the files and sorted folders
$basePath = "C:\test\Docs"

# This sets that folder as your CWD (Current working directory)
Set-Location $basePath

# This grabs the *files* underneath the parent directory, ignoring sub directories
$files = Get-ChildItem $basePath | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}

# Starts iterating through each file
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Split the base file name by underscore (creates an array with each part of the name seperated)
    $split = $file.BaseName -split "_"
    # Store the second item [1] in the array $split as the root folder name
    $root = "$basePath\$($split[1])"
    # Store the first item [0] in the array $split as the sub folder name
    $sub = "$root\$($split[0])"

    # Check if the root folder exists, create it if not
    if (!(Test-Path $root -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-Item $root -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    # Check if the sub folder exists, create it if not
    if (!(Test-Path $sub -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-Item $sub -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    # Move the file to the sub folder
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $sub -Verbose
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to solve your problem:

```js
#Requires -Version 4.0

function Move-FileToDirectoryWithSamePrefix
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript( {Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})] 
        [string]
        $DirectoryToMoveFileTo,

        
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [ValidateScript( {Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})] 
        [string]
        $DirectoryToSearchFiles
        )

        Begin {
           # Needed to find all files for movement
           $fileRegex = ".*_[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{4}_.*\.pdf"
           $currentLocation = Get-Location
        }
        Process{

           # find files to move
           $matchingFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryToSearchFiles -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $fileRegex }

           # Change to destination directory
           Set-Location $DirectoryToMoveFileTo

           foreach ($file in $matchingFile) {
                $directoryName = ($file -split "_")[0]

                # Find the director to move to
                $dirToMoveFile = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include $directoryName

                if ($dirToMoveFile -eq $null) {
                    # Create directory if not existing
                    $dirToMoveFile =  New-Item -Name $directoryName -Path $DirectoryToMoveFileTo -ItemType Directory
                }

                Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dirToMoveFile.fullName
           }
        }
        End{
            Set-Location $currentLocation
        }
}
```

Store above in a ps1 file, e.g. `moveFile.ps1`. Afterwards open a PowerShell and source the file:

```
PS C:\> . C:\PathToYourPs1File\moveFile.ps1
```

Afterwards you can the function like:

```
PS C:\temp> Move-FileToDirectoryWithSamePrefix -DirectoryToMoveFileTo .\filesDestination -DirectoryToSearchFiles .\files
```

If you need to debug it open the ps1 in the Powershell ISE, set a breakpoint and start the script. For further information see this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/24/use-the-debugger-in-the-windows-powershell-ise/).

Hope that helps.